# Remove delivery address from Paypal checkout?

Tags: paypal

I have a Paypal form on my website, but for some reason when the user goes to the checkout Page on Paypal's website, it shows their 'delivery address'. Does anyone know how I can remove this? Thank you

```
        <section style="background-color:white;border-radius:25px;" 
id="three" class="wrapper style3 special">
                    <div class="container 50%">


                  <form id="Order" name="Order" 
 action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<h2 style="color:black;">Your Page:</h2>    <input type="hidden" 
name="on0" value="URL" />
<input style="border:1px solid grey;" name="os0" type="text" 
class="formtext" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<h2 style="color:black;">Your Email Address:</h2>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="EMAIL" />
 <input style="border:1px solid grey;" name="os1" type="text" 
class="formtext" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalemail; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="U">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Product Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $bronze_price; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the 
seller">
<br />
<br />
<table width="50px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<p style="color:black;">You have read and agreed to our <a style="text-
decoration:underline;" href="http://mywebsite.com/terms-of-service" 
target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>  
              <tr onclick="document['Order'].submit()">
  <td style="background-color:#3cadd4;width:5px;cursor: pointer;"><div><a 
style="color:white;" href="#" onclick="document['Order'].submit()">PAY 
NOW</a> 
</div></td>

</tr>

</table>
    <p style="color:black;">Price: $<?php echo $bronze_price; ?></p>

</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the parameter "no_shipping =1" in the PayPal button code and on the PayPal checkout page Delivery address will be removed.

no_shipping No
Do not prompt buyers for a shipping address.

Valid value is:

0 - Prompt for an address, but do not require one.

1 - Do not prompt for an address.

2 - Prompt for an address and require one.

Default is 0.

Refer the following link for more information about PayPal Button HTML variables: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/